# Structure map .Ignore a type while verifying the container

Tags: c#, structuremap

I am getting this error while verifying my Structuremap configuration using 
`container.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` in my UnitTest.

`No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily MyComp.IMeasureRepository.`

Infact for this particular Interface i dont have any plans for dependency injection.So can we make the Stucturemap ignore this Interface and still pass my UnitTest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something else that is registered with StructureMap likely takes an `IMeasureRepository` as a dependency. StructureMap needs to know how to satisfy that dependency.

Comment: So AssertConfigurationIsValid was doing its job. That's exactly why it exists: to search out the stuff you overlooked. Trust it!

Answer (score 1):

I figure the interface is registered as part of a scan and not as a ctor argument. While scanning you can selectively include or exclude assemblies, namespaces and types.

You should be able to use
`ExcludeType<IMeasureRepository>()`
in the scanning configuration.

Example:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(c =>
    {
        c.Scan(scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                scan.ExcludeType<IMeasureRepository>();
            });
    });
```

See the [Scan documentation](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ScanningAssemblies.htm) for further details.